# RuntimeError: Method requires being in cross-replica context, use get_replica_context().merge_call() while using tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to change a model to multiple gpus using mirrored_strategy.
I was able to replicate my issue on a simpler model, which is in
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16YlKuzdluryVRmcM680tjtLWfPjt5qhS

But here is the important part of the code;

```
def loss_object(target_y, pred_y):
    pred_ssum = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(pred_y))
    target_ssum = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(target_y))
    mul_sum = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(pred_y, target_y))
    return tf.math.divide(-2 * mul_sum, tf.math.add(pred_ssum, target_ssum))

EPOCHS = 10



model = MyModel()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5)

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')

test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='test_loss')
test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='test_accuracy')

@tf.function
def distributed_train_step(images, labels):
    per_replica_losses = mirrored_strategy.experimental_run_v2(train_step, args=(images, labels,))
    return mirrored_strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses,
                        axis=None)

@tf.function
def distributed_test_step(images, labels):
    return mirrored_strategy.experimental_run_v2(test_step, args=(images, labels,))

@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(images, training=True)
        loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    
    #train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy.update_state(labels, predictions)

@tf.function
def test_step(images, labels):
    predictions = model(images, training=False)
    t_loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)

    test_loss.update_state(t_loss)
    test_accuracy.update_state(labels, predictions)

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
# Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
    total_loss = 0.0
    num_batches = 0

    for images, labels in train_ds:
        #train_step(images, labels)
        total_loss += distributed_train_step(images, labels)
        num_batches += 1
    train_loss = total_loss/num_batches

    for test_images, test_labels in test_ds:
        #test_step(test_images, test_labels)
        distributed_test_step(test_images, test_labels)

    template = 'Epoch {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}, Test Loss: {}, Test Accuracy: {}'
    print(template.format(epoch+1, train_loss, train_accuracy.result()*100, test_loss.result(), test_accuracy.result()*100))

    train_accuracy.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    test_accuracy.reset_states()
```

All the code above is in mirrored_strategy.scope():
The model just simply takes (4,4,4) cube with constant values and goes through two 3D_CNN and 3D_CNN_Transpose layers to get the same (4,4,4) cube as output.

However, I get an error saying

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-93fb783af116> in <module>()
     65         for images, labels in train_ds:
     66             #train_step(images, labels)
---> 67             total_loss += distributed_train_step(images, labels)
     68             num_batches += 1
     69         train_loss = total_loss/num_batches

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

RuntimeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-19-93fb783af116>:32 distributed_train_step  *
        per_replica_losses = mirrored_strategy.experimental_run_v2(train_step, args=(images, labels,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py:770 _call_for_each_replica  *
        fn, args, kwargs)
    <ipython-input-19-93fb783af116>:43 train_step  *
        predictions = model(images, training=True)
    <ipython-input-14-cb5f0d1313e2>:9 call  *
        with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:291 __enter__
        self._context.strategy.extended)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:214 _require_cross_replica_or_default_context_extended
        raise RuntimeError("Method requires being in cross-replica context, use "

    RuntimeError: Method requires being in cross-replica context, use get_replica_context().merge_call()
```

Has anybody faced a similar problem? It would be grateful if somebody provides me with a suggestion.

Comment: I'm struggling with this one too. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: The colab link that you provided is not accessible. Can you provide the accessible-link for the colab? So we can inspect all the related information that we need.

Comment: @TF_Support I corrected the link! It would be great if you could check. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the train_step in distribute_train_step function causes the error and requiring you to use get_replica_context().merge_call().
Try implementing it with your code. You can check the documentation for this. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/get_replica_context

Comment: @TF_Support Could you please elaborate more? I looked at the document but have no idea where and how I should use that function. Like, what function should it be in? 

If it helps, https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training
this is the tutorial I'm trying to follow.

Thank you!

Comment: After several re-inspection, Trying your custom model "MyModel" on the working code of the tutorial you gave, produces the same error. Which means the model is the real culprit here. Tried using a different model in your code and it worked well. You should modify your model that works with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion, the Model was indeed the cause of this error. Below corrections is the working running code for this problem.

In your dataset changing the datatype of ***int*** to ***float*** will prevent a future **TypeError**.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
!pip install tf-nightly
#%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models, Model
import numpy as np

mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

def train_gen():
    for i in range(10):
      yield tf.constant(i, shape=(4,4,4,1)), tf.constant(i, shape=(4,4,4,1))

def test_gen():
    for i in range(2):
      yield tf.constant(i+10, shape=(4,4,4,1)), tf.constant(i+10, shape=(4,4,4,1))

BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA = 2
GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE = BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA * mirrored_strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    train_gen,
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),    # using float as your datatype
    output_shapes=((4,4,4,1), (4,4,4,1))
)

test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    test_gen,
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),      # using float as your datatype
    output_shapes=((4,4,4,1), (4,4,4,1))
)

train_ds = train_ds.batch(GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE)
test_ds = test_ds.batch(GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE)
```

On your model, the ***mirrored_strategy.scope()*** causes the error you are encountering. Removing this as the below code, will solve this problem.

```
class MyModel(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        #with mirrored_strategy.scope():
        self.cnn_down_1 = layers.Conv3D(1, (2, 2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')
        self.cnn_up_1 = layers.Conv3DTranspose(1, (2, 2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')

    def call(self, inputs):
         #with mirrored_strategy.scope():
            x = self.cnn_down_1(inputs)
            return self.cnn_up_1(x) 

assert tf.distribute.get_replica_context() is not None  # default
```

On the part of code below, removing ***@tf.function*** before the `train_step` and `test_step` function is necessary.

```
with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    #assert tf.distribute.get_replica_context() is not None  # default
    loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
    def loss_object(target_y, pred_y):
        pred_ssum = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(pred_y))
        target_ssum = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.square(target_y))
        mul_sum = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(pred_y, target_y))
        return tf.math.divide(-2 * mul_sum, tf.math.add(pred_ssum, target_ssum))

    EPOCHS = 10



    model = MyModel()

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5)

    train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
    train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')

    test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='test_loss')
    test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='test_accuracy')

    #@tf.function
    def train_step(images, labels):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = model(images, training=True)
            loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

        #train_loss(loss)
        train_accuracy.update_state(labels, predictions)
        return loss

    #@tf.function
    def test_step(images, labels):
        predictions = model(images, training=False)
        t_loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)

        test_loss.update_state(t_loss)
        test_accuracy.update_state(labels, predictions)


    @tf.function
    def distributed_train_step(images, labels):
      assert tf.distribute.get_replica_context() is None
      per_replica_losses = mirrored_strategy.experimental_run_v2(train_step, args=(images, labels,))
      return mirrored_strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses,
                          axis=None)

    @tf.function
    def distributed_test_step(images, labels):
        return mirrored_strategy.experimental_run_v2(test_step, args=(images, labels,))


    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    # Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
        #train_loss.reset_states()
        total_loss = 0.0
        num_batches = 0

        for images, labels in train_ds:
            #train_step(images, labels)
            total_loss += distributed_train_step(images, labels)
            num_batches += 1
        train_loss = total_loss/num_batches

        for test_images, test_labels in test_ds:
            #test_step(test_images, test_labels)
            distributed_test_step(test_images, test_labels)

        template = 'Epoch {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}, Test Loss: {}, Test Accuracy: {}'
        print(template.format(epoch+1, train_loss, train_accuracy.result()*100, test_loss.result(), test_accuracy.result()*100))

        train_accuracy.reset_states()
        test_loss.reset_states()
        test_accuracy.reset_states()
```

This solves the problem and properly removed the error. This is now working. Hope this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have also similar error saying
`` RuntimeError: `apply_gradients() cannot be called in cross-replica context. Use `tf.distribute.Strategy.run` to enter replica context. `` The error change when I remove `@tf.function`  as @TF_Support said in his answer.